# What is the Migration Threshold for data distribution across shards in mongodb-6.0?

Tags: database, mongodb, sharding

In earlier mongodb version, there are some migration threshold depending on chunks migration across shards, such as below -

| Number of chunks in a collection | Migration threshold value |
| --- | --- |
| [1, 20) | 2 |
| [20, 80) | 4 |

For current version 6.0, data in sharded clusters is distributed based on data size rather than number of chunks. What is the migration threshold depending on current procedure?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In mongoDB 6.0, the default range size to migrate between two shard is 128MB.
The migration threshold in this version is 3x rang size.
That's good to reduce the overhead of migration process between shards.